# Alert if ANY radio options are not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a form with 3 questions that have 3 radio options each. I want the form to send an alert if ANY of the questions are left blank. This code sends an alert only if ALL of the questions are left blank:

```
if (!$("input").is(':checked')) {
    alert("You left one blank!");
}
```

So, for example, if I have only one question answered, I want the alert to send. Instead, it continues on with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 radio groups, so there will be 3 checked inputs and 6 unchecked inputs, I suggest:

```
if ( $("input[type=radio]:checked").length < 3 ) {
    alert('Please answer all of the questions');
}
```

Comment: Haha interesting, I can't believe I didn't think of that. This would only work if the `input[radio]` for each question are grouped together (by name) though. So hopefully, and I would guess, they are.

Comment: +1 but the disadvantage would be needing to update the hardcoded 3 every time the number of questions changed.

Comment: Since I know the number of questions will never change and I did group the input[radio] for each question, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").on("click", function () {
        var count = 0;
        var questions = $("div.question");
        questions.each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("input").filter('[type="radio"]').filter(":checked").length > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        if (count >= questions.length) {
            alert("all good");
        } else {
            alert("something not checked");
        }
    });
});
```

With the HTML:

```
<div class="question">
    Question 1:
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" />
</div>

<div class="question">
    Question 2:
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" />
</div>

<div class="question">
    Question 3:
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4yQHv/1/

You can change `if (count >= questions.length) {` to be `===` instead of `>=` to make sure exactly 1 radio button is chosen for every question. Otherwise, this allows for more than one radio button to be chosen (which isn't exactly possible when they're grouped by `name` attribute)...but just wanted to point that out.

Comment: Three questions each having three radio buttons... Isn't it so, that there should be still six unchecked buttons?

Comment: @MartinSmith I just updated. I think it's working as expected now

Comment: Updated again, with what I think is better. It doesn't need hardcoded numbers in for how many questions/areas there are. The only thing required is that each question be identifiable - in my example, by the `question` class.

Comment: Thanks for your work! The other solution has less code, though, so I'm going to go with that.

Comment: @Pixel No problem. If you're seriously going with an answer because it has less code, then good luck. Haha that's not always the best answer

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tVUuW/

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="facepunch" class="facepunch" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="facepunch" class="facepunch" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="facepunch" class="facepunch" value="3" />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="stack" class="stack" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="stack" class="stack" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="stack" class="stack" value="3" />
    <br />
    <input id="button" type="button">
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if(!$("input.facepunch:checked").val()) {
            alert("Please select facepunch");
        }

        if(!$("input.stack:checked").val()) {
            alert("Please select stack");
        }
    });
});
```

If you have only few groups of radios you can use this method, this is one way to validate user data.

I recommend you to check out one of the great jQuery Validation Plugins out there:
[jzaefferer plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation), [bassistance plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Also, Make sure you validate it on the server side as well! The user can send request to your server from somewhere else or even disable javascript on his browser

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through all your radio buttons and see if any of them is unchecked:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
       if( ! $(this).is(':checked') ) {
           alert('You left one blank!');
           return false; //exit function, so alert won't show multiple times
       }
    });
```

[**Example**](http://jsbin.com/ubuxuf/1/edit)

Comment: This creates an infinite loop--the "You left one blank!" alert wont go away.